# With Centos 7 as a Virtualbox guest on a Mac Host, how can I change the screen resolution of the console / command line?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, centos, grub

I am using the minimum install of CentOS 7 with command line access only (no graphic support installed).

After spending hours reading online about editing grub files, installing guest additions, and setting VB options, absolutely nothing is working for me.

First, guest additions is installed. Secondly, the only grub file I have is /boot/grub2/grub.cfg, and it says not to edit it as it's dynamically generated. Finally, editing the Display under VB's > Machine > settings to automatic, none, or hint with the resolution I want does not make a difference.

Step by step, what exactly do I have to do in order to get my screen resolution to be larger than 640 x 400 as well as provide for a buffer (currently there is no buffer)?

Comment: This doesn't solve the screen size issue, but a work around maybe just to SSH into the vm if you don't need the console all the time

Answer (score 24):

CentOS 7 still uses the [deprecated](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks#Setting_the_framebuffer_resolution) vga parameter.
You wanted step-by-step, you get it:

1. Make yourself root: `sudo su`
2. `vi /etc/default/grub`
3. In Vi, press `i` or `Insert`-key on your keyboard to enter the edit mode.
4. Add **`vga=792`** inside the "-quotes for **`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`**, f.ex. `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet vga=792"`
5. Press `Esc` and type `:wq` and hit `Enter` to save and exit Vi.
6. `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`
7. `reboot`

This procedure applies not just Mac, but all *host operating systems* running Virtualbox: Windows, Linux.

@garethTheRed's answer might work in some versions of some Linux distros, but the trick is to find the correct parameters for your environment. At least with some Red Hat distros you need to fall back to old, deprecated habits.

Comment: Works. So CentOS 7 still uses `vga` param.. BTW `vga=792` will give you a **1024x768** resolution.

Comment: http://pierre.baudu.in/other/grub.vga.modes.html has other codes for this. 795 is 1280x1024 at 24bit depth. Here is the chart from that without formatting... sorry                                                                                               

    Colour depth 640x480 800x600 1024x768 1280x1024 1400x1050 1600x1200
    8 (256) 769 771 773 775 
    15 (32K) 784 787 790 793  
    16 (65K) 785 788 791 794 834 884
24 (16M) 786 789 792 795

Answer (score 8):

Above all, I followed in **@John Mayor**'s steps and made up a specific way. hope it helps to someone.

---

[Tested Environment]

CentOS 7.4.1708 on VMWARE Workstation 12 Player
(kernel 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64)

---

1. Edit `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` value in `/etc/default/grub` file

   > Before :`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto ... rhgb quiet"`
   >   After    :`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto ... rhgb quiet vga=ask"`
2. [Grub Update](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152222/equivalent-of-update-grub-for-rhel-fedora-centos-systems/152249#answer-152249)

   > grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg   ( CentOS, Tested )
   >   grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.conf ( Fedora, Not Tested )
3. Reboot
4. A message is displayed like below, press `<ENTER>`

   > Press `<ENTER>` to see video modes available. `<SPACE>` to continue. or wait 30 sec
5. Choose one of the out values and note it
   [Display example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu1xt.png)

   > example row ) **z 342** 1152x864x32 VESA
6. Type `z` and press `<ENTER>` for test
7. Boot continues. after boot, confirm the resolution is changed.
8. Edit `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` value in `/etc/default/grub` file again
   change vga value from ask to `0x0342` **what you memoized value previous step**.
   ※ Display mode number must be `hexadecimal`. or not, it would be [`undefined video mode number 342`](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?209737-quot-Undefined-Video-Mode-Number-quot-at-Boot) printed

   > Before :`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto ... rhgb quiet vga=ask"`
   >   After    :`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto ... rhgb quiet vga=0x0342"`
9. Grub Update again

   > grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg ( CentOS )
   >   grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.conf ( Fedora )
10. Reboot and confirm it.

Comment: Great. Now I know why I set `792` but in grub I see different values.

Comment: Any chance to get greater resolution than 1152x864?

Answer (score 2):

You need to inform the guest's kernel of the required size of your terminal.

At the `grub` prompt, use the cursor keys to move to the kernel that you are intending to boot and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key to edit.  Use the cursor key to move to the line that starts `linux` and at the end of the line add:

```
video=800x600-24
```

for 800 x 600 resolution with 24 bit colour.

Press whatever key combination `grub` needs to boot.

If that works, you'll need to make this permanent:

Modify `/etc/default/grub` and append the stanza above to the `GRUB_CMD_LINE` line.

Next run:

```
# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

which will make 800x600@24 the default for all current and future kernels.

Comment: good test approach.